# Connecting Zynq boards in deterministic way

Tags: networking, cluster-computing, real-time, xilinx, zynq

I'm trying to make a cluster with Zynq-7010 boards for a real-time application. One of them will be the master, and it will control eight client boards. The master board will also collect the data from clients. I tried to use 100Mbit ethernet connection to connect the nodes but it was not as fast as I need. In addition, it was not deterministic because of switch's indeterministic behavior. Could you give me some idea about how to connect them fast and deterministic way?

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed it up is to use 1Gbit ethernet, which is supported by Zynq-7010, if you have an appropriate ethernet transceiver on the board.

If you have FMC connectors, you could use an [FMC Ethernet](http://ethernetfmc.com/) board to enable the master to connect directly to 4 other boards to avoid the non-determinism of an ethernet switch.